# Have different colors on Navigation Bars?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uinavigationbar

Hi is it possible to have different colors on different Navigation Bars? I have this code in my AppDelegate.m. I basically want to be able to change the color of the different Navigation Bars in different views.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xac1f2d)];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Rephrase you question accordingly what do you want?

Comment: It has now been edited.

Answer (score 0):

You set a image to its backgorund of `[UINavigationBar appearance ]` in your `Delegate` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In your view controllers' `viewWillAppear` you can set --

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor` to your required colour.